# How to show the edit form and selected value in option field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here i want to do,some one click edit button means, i want show the edit form in same page and in that edit form i want to show already what value wrote,that value i want to display in that form field,here i did for truck name becauze this one for input=text ,but next field i am not able to show which state already he selected,how can do this

```js
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trucks WHERE status !='1' ORDER BY reg_date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$cat=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<tr>
   <td>'.$row["truck_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.Getstate($row["state_id"]).'</td>
   <td>'.Getcity($row["city_id"]).'</td>
   
   <td class="col-medium center">
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs ">
   <a class="btn btn-inverse" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="show_edit_menu(\''.$row["id"].'\',\''.$row["truck_name"].'\',\''.$row["state_id"].'\',\''.$row["city_id"].'\')"><i class="fa fa-edit icon-only"></i>Edit</a>
   <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="truck_deletemenu('.$row["id"].')"><i class="fa fa-times icon-only"></i>Delete</a>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>';
}

?><?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trucks WHERE status !='1' ORDER BY reg_date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$cat=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<tr>
   <td>'.$row["truck_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.Getstate($row["state_id"]).'</td>
   <td>'.Getcity($row["city_id"]).'</td>
   
   <td class="col-medium center">
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs ">
   <a class="btn btn-inverse" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="show_edit_menu(\''.$row["id"].'\',\''.$row["truck_name"].'\',\''.$row["state_id"].'\',\''.$row["city_id"].'\')"><i class="fa fa-edit icon-only"></i>Edit</a>
   <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="truck_deletemenu('.$row["id"].')"><i class="fa fa-times icon-only"></i>Delete</a>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>';
}

?>
  
  
  <script>
 function show_edit_menu(id,t_name,state_id,city_id){
 $("#show_edit_menu").show();
 
 $("#tid").val(id);//truck auto id
 $("#tname").val(t_name);//Truck Name
 $("#state").val(state_id);//state id
 
 console.log(t_name);//i got truck name value here
 console.log(state_id);//i got state name value here
 
 
 }
</script>
```

```html
<!--edit part here-->
<div class="portlet" id="show_edit_menu" style="display:none;">
<div class="portlet-heading dark">
<div class="portlet-title">
 <h4>Edit Menu</h4>
</div>
<div class="portlet-widgets">
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#f-3"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="f-3" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="portlet-body">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="edit_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Truck Name<span class="require">*</span></label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="tname" id="tname">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="" name="tid" id="tid">
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">State<span class="require">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
       <select class="form-control intro-form-fixer state" required="" id="state" name="state" data-msg-required="Please enter your State" value="" aria-required="true">
       <option value="1"> I want to show which state i selected</option>
     </select>
     <!--<input type="hidden" id="state" name="state" value="" />-->
     </div>
    </div>
  
  
  <div class="form-actions">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit_menu()">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 2 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: K tell me the solution of my requirement

Comment: Solve the more important problem first. Any decent programmer here will refuse to help you build upon your own demise.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("#state option[value='"+state_id+"']").attr("selected", true);
```

**instead of**

```
$("#state").val(state_id);
```